# Can't get navbar to work with Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Ive been struggling long time with the navbar for my wordpress Theme im developing.

I can't get it to display the navbar correctly.

Here is my code from header.php:

```
  <body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>

            </button>

            <a class="brand" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>"<?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a>

          <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
             <ul class="nav">

              <?php wp_list_pages('sort_column=menu_order'); ?>

              </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </nav>    
    <div class="container">
```

EDIT:

Heres a link to screenshot of what I wish and what it looks like now.

[image]

Comment: How does your render look, can we get a picture/description of how it looks and what you really want to achieve?

Comment: Added a link to screenshot with the wish outcome.

Comment: You are missing `navbar-nav` class in your `<ul class="nav">`. It has to be       `<ul class="nav navbar-nav">`.

Comment: It didnt help, nothing really changed.

Comment: And also `collapse navbar-collapse` class should be instead `<div class="nav-collapse collapse">`.

Comment: Google for Bootstrap 3 navwalker

Comment: did bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js really linked before?

Comment: It seems you're using deprecated styles

Answer (score 0):

Check this out on GitHub.

https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker

I think this will help.